# How do I use multiple threads with PySide and Twython?

Tags: python, twitter, pyside, twython

I'm trying to write a small python app, using [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) for the GUI and [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) as a Twitter API library, to catch a stream from Twitter.

The problem that I am having is that when I click "Start Monitoring Twitter" button, the UI freezes until the stream is complete, at which point the code continues to execute and disables the Start button and enables the Stop button. Here's the UI:

[image]

Everything else seems to work -- if I leave it, then the CSV file is created as I suspect -- the Twython components seem to be working as expected.

Line 151 is where the streaming from Twitter is engaged when I click start:

```
self.stream.statuses.filter(track=self.search_term)
```

How can I move the streaming to a separate thread and then use the Stop button on the UI to tell Twython to complete capturing the stream and exit?

I need to be able to send the `MyStreamer` instance to another thread and then send it the `.disconnect()` signal to have it terminate capturing the stream.

Here's the full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import platform
import PySide

from PySide.QtGui   import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QCheckBox, QTextEdit
from time           import sleep
from ui_tweetstream import Ui_MainWindow
from twython        import Twython
from twython        import TwythonStreamer

import csv

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Set up Variables
        self.tweet_fav_count           = True
        self.tweet_geocoordinates      = True
        self.tweet_id                  = True
        self.tweet_language            = True
        self.tweet_orig_tweet_id       = True
        self.tweet_orig_username       = True
        self.tweet_retweeted           = True
        self.tweet_sensitive           = True
        self.tweet_source_app          = True
        self.tweet_timestamp           = True
        self.tweet_user_name           = True
        self.search_term               = "#bigdata"
        self.tweets_to_get             = 1000

        # Bind the interface
        self.check_tweet_fav_count.clicked.connect(self.setTweetFavCount)
        self.check_tweet_geocoordinates.clicked.connect(self.setTweetGeocoordinates)
        self.check_tweet_id.clicked.connect(self.setTweetID)
        self.check_tweet_language.clicked.connect(self.setTweetLanguage)
        self.check_tweet_orig_tweet_id.clicked.connect(self.setTweetOrigTweetID)
        self.check_tweet_orig_username.clicked.connect(self.setTweetOrigUsername)
        self.check_tweet_retweeted.clicked.connect(self.setTweetRetweeted)
        self.check_tweet_sensitive.clicked.connect(self.setTweetSensitive)
        self.check_tweet_source_app.clicked.connect(self.setTweetSourceApp)
        self.check_tweet_timestamp.clicked.connect(self.setTweetTimestamp)
        self.check_tweet_user_name.clicked.connect(self.setTweetUsername)
        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.streamStart)
        self.button_stop.clicked.connect(self.streamStop)

        # Set the initial states
        self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)

        APP_KEY            = ''
        APP_SECRET         = ''
        OAUTH_TOKEN        = ''
        OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

        self.t = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
        self.stream = MyStreamer(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET,OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
        self.stream.init_mainWindow(self)

    def streamStop(self):
        print "Stopping stream"
        # Enable other controls here
        self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)
        self.button_start.setEnabled(True)
        self.setControlStates(True)
        self.stream.stopStream()

    def setControlStates(self, state):
        self.check_tweet_fav_count.setEnabled(state)
        self.check_tweet_geocoordinates.setEnabled(state)
        self.check_tweet_id.setEnabled(state)
        self.check_tweet_language.setEnabled(state)
        self.check_tweet_orig_tweet_id.setEnabled(state)
        self.check_tweet_orig_username.setEnabled(state)
        self.check_tweet_retweeted.setEnabled(state)
        self.check_tweet_sensitive.setEnabled(state)
        self.check_tweet_source_app.setEnabled(state)
        self.check_tweet_timestamp.setEnabled(state)
        self.check_tweet_user_name.setEnabled(state)
        self.search_box.setEnabled(state)
        self.num_tweets_box.setEnabled(state)

    # Functions for determining what to track
    def setTweetFavCount(self):
        self.tweet_fav_count = not self.tweet_fav_count
        print "tweet_fav_count:", self.tweet_fav_count

    def setTweetGeocoordinates(self):
        self.tweet_geocoordinates = not self.tweet_geocoordinates
        print "tweet_geocoordinates:", self.tweet_geocoordinates

    def setTweetID(self):
        self.tweet_id = not self.tweet_id
        print "tweet_id:", self.tweet_id

    def setTweetLanguage(self):
        self.tweet_language = not self.tweet_language
        print "tweet_language:", self.tweet_language

    def setTweetOrigTweetID(self):
        self.tweet_orig_tweet_id = not self.tweet_orig_tweet_id
        print "tweet_orig_tweet_id:", self.tweet_orig_tweet_id

    def setTweetOrigUsername(self):
        self.tweet_orig_username = not self.tweet_orig_tweet_id
        print "tweet_orig_username:", self. tweet_orig_username

    def setTweetRetweeted(self):
        self.tweet_retweeted = not self.tweet_retweeted
        print "tweet_retweeted:", self.tweet_retweeted

    def setTweetSensitive(self):
        self.tweet_sensitive = not self.tweet_sensitive
        print "tweet_sensitive:", self.tweet_sensitive

    def setTweetSourceApp(self):
        self.tweet_source_app = not self.tweet_source_app
        print "tweet_source_app:", self.tweet_source_app

    def setTweetTimestamp(self):
        self.tweet_timestamp = not self.tweet_timestamp
        print "tweet_timestamp:", self.tweet_timestamp

    def setTweetUsername(self):
        self.tweet_user_name = not self.tweet_user_name
        print "tweet_user_name:", self.tweet_user_name

    # Functions for starting and stopping the stream
    def streamStart(self):
        print "Starting stream"
        self.setControlStates(False)

        # Disable other controls here
        self.button_start.setEnabled(False)
        self.button_stop.setEnabled(True)

        # Hack to try to disable the UI
        # sleep(0.25)

        # Get the active search term
        self.search_term = self.search_box.text()

        # Get the number of tweets
        self.tweets_to_get = int(self.num_tweets_box.text())

        # Set the streamer
        self.stream.set_start_criteria(self.tweets_to_get)
        self.stream.statuses.filter(track=self.search_term)



class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
    def init_mainWindow(self, the_main_window):
        self.main_window = the_main_window
        self.stop        = False
        self.header_done = False

    def set_start_criteria(self, numTweets):
        self.maxTweets   = numTweets
        self.tweetCount  = 0
        print "Number of tweets to get:", self.maxTweets

    def stopStream(self):
        self.stop = True

    def on_success(self, data):
        if 'text' in data:
            self.tweetCount += 1
            print "tweetCount:", self.tweetCount
            #tweet = data['text'].encode('utf-8')
            theTweet = data
            writer   = TweetMonkey()
            writer.assignMainWindow(self.main_window, self.header_done)
            self.header_done = True
            writer.process(theTweet)

        # Want to disconnect after the first result?
        if self.stop is True or self.tweetCount >= self.maxTweets:
            self.disconnect()

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        print status_code, data




class TweetMonkey:
    def assignMainWindow(self,the_main_window, is_header_done):
        self.main_window = the_main_window
        self.header_done = is_header_done

    def clean(self,text):
        text = text.replace("\n","; ")
        text = text.replace('"', "'")
        text = text.replace(','," ")
        return text

    def create_header(self):
        header = []
        tweets = open("tweets.csv", 'ab+')
        wr     = csv.writer(tweets, dialect='excel')

        if self.main_window.tweet_id is True:
            header.append("id")
        if self.main_window.tweet_language is True:
            header.append("lang")
        if self.main_window.tweet_user_name is True:
            header.append("user_name")

        header.append("tweet")

        if self.main_window.tweet_retweeted is True:
            header.append("retweeted")

        if self.main_window.tweet_fav_count is True:
            header.append("favorite_count")

        if self.main_window.tweet_source_app is True:
            header.append("source")

        if self.main_window.tweet_orig_tweet_id is True:
            header.append("in_reply_to_status_id")

        if self.main_window.tweet_orig_username is True:
            header.append("in_reply_to_screen_name")

        # header.append("in_reply_to_user_id")

        if self.main_window.tweet_sensitive is True:
            header.append("possibly_sensitive")

        if self.main_window.tweet_geocoordinates is True:
            header.append("geo")

        if self.main_window.tweet_timestamp is True:
            header.append("created_at")

        wr.writerow(header)
        tweets.close()

    def process(self, tweet):
        if not self.header_done:
            self.create_header()
            self.header_done = True

        # Create the file or append to the existing
        theOutput = []
        tweets = open("tweets.csv", 'ab+')
        wr = csv.writer(tweets, dialect='excel')

        if self.main_window.tweet_id is True:
            theOutput.append(tweet['id'])

        if self.main_window.tweet_language is True:
            theOutput.append(tweet['lang'].encode('utf-8'))

        if self.main_window.tweet_user_name is True:
            theOutput.append(tweet['user']['name'].encode('utf-8', 'replace'))

        theOutput.append(self.clean(tweet['text']).encode('utf-8', 'replace'))

        if self.main_window.tweet_retweeted is True:
            theOutput.append(tweet['retweeted'])

        if self.main_window.tweet_fav_count is True:
            theOutput.append(tweet['favorite_count'])

        if self.main_window.tweet_source_app is True:
            theOutput.append(self.clean(tweet['source']).encode('utf-8', 'replace'))

        if self.main_window.tweet_orig_tweet_id is True:
            theOutput.append(tweet['in_reply_to_status_id'])

        if self.main_window.tweet_orig_username is True:
            theOutput.append(tweet['in_reply_to_screen_name'])

        #theOutput.append(tweet['in_reply_to_user_id'])

        if self.main_window.tweet_sensitive is True:
            if tweet.get('possibly_sensitive'):
                theOutput.append(tweet['possibly_sensitive'])
            else:
                theOutput.append("False")

        if self.main_window.tweet_geocoordinates is True:
            if tweet['geo'] is not None:
                if tweet['geo']['type'] == 'Point':
                    lat = str(tweet['geo']['coordinates'][0]) + " "
                    lon = str(tweet['geo']['coordinates'][1])
                    theOutput.append(lat + lon)
                else:
                    theOutput.append(tweet['geo'])
            else:
                theOutput.append(tweet['geo'])

        if self.main_window.tweet_timestamp is True:
            theOutput.append(tweet['created_at'])

        wr.writerow(theOutput)
        tweets.close()





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I ran into a similar problem in a simple app I recently wrote, my solution was to use threading.

I used the worker from:
https://pymotw.com/2/threading/

and the method described in:
http://aadrake.com/using-twitter-as-a-stream-processing-source.html

Basically running the Twython stream as a separate thread feeding text to a queue then I run the rest of the program in a separate loop reading from the queue.